# Incrementação dos hooks no react

Tags: react

Estou me aventurando no mundo do React e percebi que agora há os *hooks*.

Gostaria de entender:

- Qual foi a necessidade de se implementar essa *feature*; e:
- Qual seria a vantagem de utilizar os *hooks* ao invés do *state*?

Comment: Recomendo você olhar esse site: https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

Comment: Se você consegue ouvir em inglês, recomendo esta palestra do time do React introduzindo o conceito de hooks. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dpw9EHDh2bM

Comment: Acho que você poderia mudar "ao invés do ***state***" para "ao invés de **classes**", tendo em vista que os hooks te permitem utilizar recursos como o estado.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Quando os hooks chegaram, fiquei meio confuso sobre as motivações para uma feature que mudaria bastante a forma como usamos o react, e esse link foi o divisor de águas para entender de fato como utilizar os hooks.

http://high5devs.com/2019/03/react-hooks/